# How to reload page on click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

What should I add to my code so that when a button is clicked (which redirects to the same page where the button is) the page reloads? I tried adding `window.location.reload();` but it just keeps reloading nonstop.

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        let desktoptitles = $('.jet-tabs__control');

        if (!$(desktoptitles).length)
            desktoptitles = $('.jet-tabs__control');

        $(desktoptitles).each(function (index, title) {

            title = $(this).text().replace(/\W/g, '');
            title = '#' + title;

            if (window.location.href.indexOf(title) > -1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    desktoptitles.eq(index).click();
                    
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: desktoptitles.eq(index).offset().top - 50
                    }, 'fast'); 
                }, 0);
            }
        });

        $(desktoptitles).click(function (index, title) {

            var current_location = window.location.href;
            current_location = current_location.split("#");

            title = $(this).text().replace(/\W/g, '');
            title = '#' + title;

            window.location = current_location[0] + title;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: `$(desktoptitles).click(function (index, title) {` since when does `click` handler take two arguments? also, where/how are you trying to add `window.location.reload();` - since that's the issue, you should show the code with the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can put this code and check

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        let desktoptitles = $('.jet-tabs__control');

        if (!$(desktoptitles).length)
            desktoptitles = $('.jet-tabs__control');

        $(desktoptitles).each(function (index, title) {

            title = $(this).text().replace(/\W/g, '');
            title = '#' + title;

            if (window.location.href.indexOf(title) > -1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  //  desktoptitles.eq(index).click();
                    
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: desktoptitles.eq(index).offset().top - 50
                    }, 'fast'); 
                }, 0);
            }
        });

        $(desktoptitles).click(function (index, title) {

            var current_location = window.location.href;
            current_location = current_location.split("#");

            title = $(this).text().replace(/\W/g, '');
            title = '#' + title;

            window.location = current_location[0] + title;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```